# "vector iterators incompatible." How can I pass it as a parameter to the function?

Tags: c++, loops, oop, vector, iterator

Why do I get the error "vector iterators incompatible" when I want to run the function "klimaTag()"? I want to give it the iterator of the vector temperatures. How can I do that? I only want to loop over the vector in the main function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TemperatureCalculator {
private:
    std::vector<float> temperatures;

public:
    TemperatureCalculator(std::vector<float> temperatures) {
        this->temperatures = temperatures;
    }

    std::string klimaTag(std::vector<float>::iterator i) {
        if (*i >= 25 and *i < 30) {
            return "Sommertag";
        }
        else if (*i >= 30 and *i < 35) {
            return "Heißer Tag";
        }
        else if (*i >= 35) {
            return "Wüstentag";
        }
        else {
            return "Normaltag";
        }
    }

    void get_user_input() {
        int numberDays;
        std::cout << "Wie viele Tage möchten Sie auswerten?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> numberDays;

        float current_temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberDays; i++) {
            std::cout << "Hoechsttemp für Tag " << i + 1 << " eingeben: ";
            std::cin >> current_temp;
            temperatures.push_back(current_temp);
        }
    }

    std::vector<float> get_temperature() {
        return this->temperatures;
    }

};

int main()
{
    TemperatureCalculator t({});
    t.get_user_input();

    for (std::vector<float>::iterator i = t.get_temperature().begin(); i != t.get_temperature().end(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Tag " << *i + 1 << " ist ein " << t.klimaTag(i) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `get_temperature` returns a different copy of the vector every time you call it. You need to return a reference.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/FQv4TzSJJUh3FPOs

Comment: @PaulSanders It is a Visual Studio iterator debugging assertion. I don't know if gcc does the same thing or not.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ah, OK, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return copy of vector in `get_temperature`, and so use iterator of temporary vector in

`std::vector<float>::iterator i = t.get_temperature().begin()`

Solution is to return reference:

```
class TemperatureCalculator {
private:
    std::vector<float> temperatures;

// ...
public:
    const std::vector<float>& get_temperature() const { return this->temperatures; }
    // Possibly:
    //std::vector<float>& get_temperature() { return this->temperatures; }
};
```

Notice that passing simple iterator seems strange whereas passing value do the job:

```
std::string klimaTag(float f) const
{
    if (25 <= f and f < 30) {
        return "Sommertag";
    }
    else if (30 <= f and f < 35) {
        return "Heißer Tag";
    }
    else if (*35 <= f) {
        return "Wüstentag";
    }
    else {
        return "Normaltag";
    }
}
```

and so your loop becomes:

```
for (float f : t.get_temperature()) {
    std::cout << "Tag " << f + 1 << " ist ein " << t.klimaTag(f) << std::endl;
}
```